# Create a folder with the name of a file using bat

Tags: batch-file

I have a file `D:\MyFile.zip`.

I want to create a directory named *"MyFile"* and want to extract the zip file inside the directory.

The path of *"MyFile"* Folder should be:

```
%cd%\MyFile\
```

Extraction part I can manage. But, Tell me about creating the Folder with the same file name, in a specified path.

Comment: Can your zip extraction process not do this automatically?  It's a very common way to of unzipping things.

Comment: O.. Please tell me the command then.. C:\ Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe x -inul -ppassword "%cd%\

Comment: Then what to write?? @Will Dean

Comment: Or forget about extraction.. Just tell me.. How to creat a folder with the name of a file, if full path of that file is specified..

Comment: I can't really tell what you're asking, but this might be helpful https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in ("yourfullfilename") do ECHO MD "%%~dpna"
```

will `ECHO` the directoryname to be created. Remove the `ECHO` keyword to activate. Append `2>nul` to suppress "directory already exists" error message.

Comment: The requirement is to create the folder in the current directory, so the OP can change `%%~dpna` to `%%~na`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
set filePath=D:\MyFile.zip

:: Get file name from path
for %%a in (%filePath:\= %) do set fileName=%%a

:: Remove file extension from file name
set fileName=%fileName:~0,-4%

echo %fileName%
```

This won't work if there is a space in the file name..